# SQL print a space between concat statements

Tags: sql, concatenation

Concatenating two columns together, Just want them to be displaying together in column with a space between the two numbers. It keeps adding the two numbers together. One is a bigint other is a smallint.Will be displayed in an SSRS report eventually but right now just using SQL to query the data

```
    (NBR +''+ ACCT_NBR) as acct,
```

Comment: Took a stab at your question without knowing the database. You should provide complete information next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't mention what flavor of SQL you're using, but depending, you may need to convert the values to strings first.  For SQLSever...

```
(Cast(NBR as varchar(20)) + ' ' + Cast(ACCT_NBR as varchar(20))) as acct,
```

Answer (score 21):

Though you didn't mention the database, try

MySQL

```
concat(NBR,' ',ACCT_NBR) as acct
```

SQL Server

```
CAST(NBR AS VARCHAR)+' '+CAST(ACCT_NBR AS VARCHAR) as acct
```

Comment: "Does not support concat". What does not support concat? We are programmers not telepaths.

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is already answered and is correct. But would like to post the below answer because from SQL Server 2017 onwards, this is too easy and someoen might find this helpful in future.

```
CONCAT_WS(CHAR(10),Cast(NBR as varchar(20)) ,Cast(ACCT_NBR as varchar(20))) as acct
```

CHAR(10) can be  for space in SQL SERVER. You can replace CHAR(10) with any separator you like to. For example,

```
CONCAT_WS(',',Cast(NBR as varchar(20)) ,Cast(ACCT_NBR as varchar(20))) as acct
```

the above query will add the separator ',' between each strings being concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

If its an Oracle Database, try

```
NBR || ' ' || ACCT_NBR as acct
```

Comment: While this code sample may possibly answer the question, it would be preferable to include some essential explanation to your answer. As it stands now this answer adds little to no value for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Stuff(Coalesce(', ' + [Address1], '') + Coalesce(', ' + [Address2], '') + Coalesce(', ' + [City], '') + Coalesce(', ' + [State], '') + Coalesce(', ' + [Country], '') +Coalesce('-' + [Zip], ''), 1, 1, '') AS [Address] FROM Customers
```

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer to explain what your proposed solution does, so it will be more useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm 7 years late, but felt like I should give this a try.

`(NBR +space(5) + ACCT_NBR) as acct`

This will add 5 whitespaces between the 2 concatenated items.
My example on how I tested was as follows:

```
select
+ N'(Contactname: '+ contactname + space(5)  + N'(Company_Name: ' + companyname + N')' + N'(Contact_Title: ' + contacttitle + N')'
from Sales.Customers
```

Answer (score -3):

In Teradata SQL you can use the below. It will always pull the last 3 days.

```
WHERE create_ts BETWEEN  (DATE -3 || ' ' || '00:00:00') AND (DATE -1 || ' ' || '23:59:59')
```

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the question at hand?